# Beginner C++ Help: if statements within if statements

Tags: c++

So recently I started learning my first language, C++ and I'm writing my own program to get some practice. To let you know how far along I am, I have just been introduced to "if" and "else if" statements in class. Here is the code:

```
// Grade Calculator

#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

float cutoffa, cutoffb, cutoffc, cutoffd, grade;
string firstname, lastname;

cout << setprecision(3) << fixed;
cout << "This program was made to test the \"if\" and \"else if\" statements.\n";
cout << "For this program you will be pretending to be a professor who is entering a student's grade.\n";
cout << "The first thing you will need to do is provide us with some basic information. Press enter when you are ready. \n";
cin.get();

cout << "What is the percent grade cut off (the lowest grade possible) for an A ? " ;
cin >> cutoffa;
cout << "What is the percent grade cut off for an B? " ;
cin >> cutoffb;
cout << "What is the percent grade cut off for an C? " ;
cin >> cutoffc;
cout << "What is the percent grade cut off for an D? " ;
cin >> cutoffd;
cout << "Enter the student's first name: ";
cin >> firstname;
cout << "Enter the student's last name: ";
cin >> lastname;
cout << "Enter the student's overall grade percentage: ";
cin >> grade;

if (grade >= cutoffa)
 cout << firstname << " " << lastname << "'s Final Grade is " << grade << "%, which is an A! Congrats!";
 else if (grade < cutoffa && grade >= cutoffb)
 cout << firstname << " " << lastname << "'s Final Grade is " << grade << "%, which is a B! Pretty good, could be better though.";
 else if (grade < cutoffb && grade >= cutoffc)
 cout << firstname << " " << lastname << "'s Final Grade is " << grade << "%, which is a C! You're average - nothing more and nothing less.";
 else if (grade < cutoffc && grade >= cutoffd)
 cout << firstname << " " << lastname << "'s Final Grade is " << grade << "% which is D! Damn, you're stupid";
 else if (grade < cutoffd)
 cout << firstname << " " << lastname << "'s Final Grade is " << grade << "% which is an F! Have you considered dropping out?";

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to be a grade calculator which takes the teacher's grade breakdown and calculates whether you have an A, B, C, D, or F in the class. I'm making this solely for the reason of practicing and it doesn't have anything to do with my C++ class.

It runs nice and all, but I've figured out a problem with it: Towards the end I put the following line of code, which applies to all the conditional statements (firstname and lastname are strings where the user enters his first/last name. cutoffa is the grade cut off for receiving an A that the user inputs):

`if (grade >= cutoffa)
     cout << firstname << " " << lastname << "'s Final Grade is " << grade << "%,       which is an A! Congrats!";`

The problem is that if someone has a name like Jake Shams, it will print out "Jake Shams's final grade is 98%, which is an A! Congrats!". The mistake here is the "Shams's" because it should be "Shams'". Like I said, I'm a beginner and this is my first time using if statements so if anyone can explain to me how to get it so that if the users last name ends with the letter S the program adds an apostrophe before the S, like so: `Jake Shams'`

Comment: Decent code, well done. We prefer that [minimal but complete] code is posted _here_, as links die and all questions on Stack Overflow are for helping future readers too, not just you now!

Comment: Thanks I'll edit the post right now!

Comment: You don't have to write `else if (grade < cutoffa && grade >= cutoffb)`, you can write `else if (grade >= cutoffb)`, because when you reach the else, `grade < cutoffa` is always true.

Comment: That's true, thanks for that!

Comment: Out of interest, where did you hear this _"it should be Sham's"_?

Comment: Whoops I meant to put Shams'

Answer (score 2):

Have an if statement checking if the name ends with an s. If it does, add an apostrophe to the original name. If not, add 's. Then remove the 's from your cout statement.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with what the code is that does that. After reading through the comments here I'm assuming   `lastname.back() == 's'` will check the if the last letter of whatever is stored in `lastname` is an 's'.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks I was able to get it to work! cpp.sh/2ziz

Comment: @przm: Your code would be better if you followed my advice. Also please use "http://" when linking so that I can go to your website without having to copy/paste; that's very fiddly on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, *Jake Shams's* is correct, so you do not need to change anything.

Some variants of English write *Jake Shams'* instead but, formally, one only drops the possessive *s* for a plural (e.g. *"all three cows' feet were digital"*).

In no correct English is the final *s* in a name altogether replaced by *'s* (like *Jake Sham's*) but, for argument's sake, you could do it like this:

```
if (grade >= cutoffa) {
     // Copy "lastname" and strip any terminating "s",
     // in advance of appending "'s" in a moment
     string lastname_possessive = lastname;
     if (lastname_possessive.back() == 's')
        lastname_possessive.pop_back();

     cout << firstname << " " << lastname_possessive << "'s Final Grade is "
          << grade << "%, which is an A! Congrats!";
}
```

However, I'd rewrite it slightly so that `lastname_possessive` contains the *whole* word. It's more reusable that way and means `lastname_possessive` the variable makes sense on its own. Like this:

```
if (grade >= cutoffa) {
     string lastname_possessive = lastname;
     if (lastname_possessive.back() == 's')
        lastname_possessive.pop_back();

     // Now do that appending
     lastname_possessive += "'s";

     cout << firstname << " " << lastname_possessive << " Final Grade is "
          << grade << "%, which is an A! Congrats!";
}
```

Now it's easier to change this to render proper English:

```
if (grade >= cutoffa) {
     string lastname_possessive = lastname;
     if (lastname_possessive.back() == 's')
        lastname_possessive += "'";  // technically wrong but sometimes used
     else
        lastname_possessive += "'s";

     cout << firstname << " " << lastname_possessive << " Final Grade is "
          << grade << "%, which is an A! Congrats!";
}
```

You'd probably want to do this outside of the conditional, actually, so that `lastname_possessive` can be used in other cases too.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `lastname` is of type `std::string`. You can then ask `if (lastname.back() == 's')`.

Comment: Thank you, yes it is a string variable. So `.back() == 's'` is the command that checks the last space in the given variable (in this case lastname)?

Comment: `std::string::back()` will return a reference to last member of given `std::string`,  in your case, last letter of `lastname`. You want it then compare against `'s'` to check if ends with `s` or not.

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be a reason for you to place an "'" before a name where the letter "s" is apart of the name.

If the person has a name that ends with "s" like "Burns" it wouldn't be right to have a program code for "Burn's".

Regardless- you could create a string, store it, and search for the "S" character (position).

On a side note for you- the accepted way of writing variable names is by using something called "CAMEL CASE" which simply means you'd write your variable "cutoffa" as "cutOffA". Every first letter of a word is capitalized except for the first initial word. It will make your code way more readable. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Complete nonsense. There is no "accepted" case convention for variable names. Everybody has their own preferences.

Comment: What about underscores?  Can the accepted way of naming a variable be "cut_off_a"?

Comment: Complete nonsense? Good like attempting to make any sort of code that is even remotely readable without using something to differentiate variable names. Camel Case is the generally accepted way for programmers. Using an underscore emphasizes the exact same practice and is fine as well.

Comment: @colt: There is no "generally accepted way", period. Although, you're a bit closer to the truth in your comment than you were in your answer, by adding the word "generally". :) Thanks for your wish of luck, though; as a senior developer I had no idea how to write "even remotely readable code" until I read your answer.

Comment: The only widely used naming convention in C++ is to use ALL_CAPS for macros and only for macros. And even that one is ignored quite often, even by the standard library itself, which has an `assert` macro.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not doubting any sort of position you may be in (Senior Developer). Also, I'm not saying his way of coding is "wrong". I will say however that if you believe a source code with hundreds of lines of code, with hundreds of variables, and possible hundreds of methods- will not be more readable by the practice of Camel Case (or underscoring)- then i really cant imagine what your code may look like :3.

I'm simply trying to share a tip, that is true because it is generally accepted as definitive among programmers alike, with the new and upcoming coder! :)

Comment: @colt: Then contribute to a large project and find out. :) I understand that you're trying to "share a tip", but I'm sitting here telling you that it is _not_ "generally accepted" with "the new and upcoming coder" or otherwise. I don't know how else to tell you that.